# Get text of property in object returned from REST

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint

I am trying to address an email to users that are in a specific list.  By expanding `Member` I can get the users email address via REST.  I can't seem to grab that email address in my script however.  How do I expand upon `Member` in `console.log(results[i]["Member"])`?

Right now that returns `[object Object]` which contains `EMail`, but I don't know the correct syntax to grab that property.

I have tried `console.log(results[i]["Email"])` , `console.log(results[i]["Member/Email"])` , and anything else that I can think of but can't seem to get it right.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<MySite>/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Member/EMail&$expand=Member",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
    success: function(d) {
        var stringData = JSON.stringify(d);
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringData);
        var results = jsonObject.d.results;
        for(i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log(results[i]["Member"]) 
        }

    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('fail');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `console.log(results[i]["Member"]["EMail"])`

You said `Member` contains `EMail` but then looked for `Email` (small m) and didn't look in `Member`.

Comment: I had tried that but I must have had the small 'm'.  When I used `EMail` it worked.  Thank you!